# Criar divisões de grid em z-index diferentes?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

É possível criar divisão de grid em um z index diferente ?

Digamos que eu tenha uma linha e uma coluna da seguinte forma:

```
<div class="row">
 <div col-md-6>

 </div>
 <div col-md-6>

 </div>
</div>
```

E que trás dessas colunas eu tenha outra divisão de colunas pra outros elementos que estão atrás do primeiro:

```
 <div col-md-4>

 </div>
 <div col-md-4>

 </div>
 <div col-md-4>

 </div>
```

Imagem de exemplo: 
[image: Exemplo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue um exemplo, não tem CSS extra, é tudo com classes do próprio Boostrap, como `position-absolut`, `d-flex`, `m-0` e `p-0`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container-fluid d-flex w-100 position-relative m-0 p-0 align-items-center">
  <div class="row w-100 m-0">
    <div class="border col-4 p-5 bg-danger">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
</div>
    <div class="border col-4 p-5 bg-danger">2</div>
    <div class="border col-4 p-5 bg-danger">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row position-absolute border w-100 m-0">
    <div class="border col-6 p-2 bg-primary">1</div>
    <div class="border col-6 p-2 bg-primary">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Apenas com cor**

Se vc só precisa de um fundo com 3 cores, sem a necessidade de um container para colocar conteúdo acho que o mais legal seria fazer um `linear-gradiente` de 3 cores.

Veja o exemplo, eu coloquei na própria `.row` um classe `.bg` com o gradiente no fundo, e dentro dessa `.row` tem duas `col-6`

```css
.bg {
 background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f0f 0%, #f0f 33.33%, #0f0 33.33%, #0f0 66.66%, #00f 66.66%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row bg py-5">
  <div class="col-6 border bg-primary">1</div>
  <div class="col-6 border bg-primary">2</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Meu problema não era exatamente com as cores mas com com uma imagem que tinha que ficar por trás de duas coluna em um canto e eu não estava conseguindo, com esse modo eu consegui com algumas alterações. Muito Obrigado

Comment: @GiovanniDias pelo menos te deu uma luz para resolver o problema, que bom que deu certo ai 